# library blocked on artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

Last week, our Maven builds were blocked because they try to download commons-io 2.4 on Artifactory. Although it is a good think to monitor libraries, I didn't find any information about the declared "XRAY-79102": why it is blocking us last week and not before, and is it linked to a publicly declared vulnerability?

Comment: Why is your build picking up  a lib which is of 2012-06-13? which means ten years plus.. why is your build not being updated (unmaintained?)

Comment: For sure, we should not do that, and we already updated our source code, but it was a dependence from openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 3.3.4. I just want to understand the mechanism behind this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `commons-io` 2.4 is 10+ years old and vulnerable (see [CVE-2021-29425](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-29425)).  You should upgrade.  The latest version is 2.14.0.

The vulnerability is 2+ years old.  Probably your company has recently added [JFrog Xray](https://jfrog.com/help/r/get-started-with-the-jfrog-platform/jfrog-xray) to your Artifactory, that's why now you are blocked.

Comment: No, it does not answers my question : of course this library is old, we should not use it, and we will update. But, according to XRAY-79102, we should update to commons-io 2.5, so this is not CVE-2021-29425, because it is fixed in 2.7

Comment: I haven't found a public description of XRAY-79102.  Since you company bought Xray you should consult its private documentation or support.  However, *if* XRAY-79102 suggests `commons-io` 2.5+ *and* XRay does not report other issues about `commons-io` *then* XRay is giving a wrong advice that should be ignored, so XRAY-79102 becomes rather irrelevant and you could report a bug to them.  Just upgrade to 2.7+ as suggested by the CVE linked in my answer.

Comment: Yes, sure we already updated, I will ask for more information, to have an idea of what is happening here.